# hidding a draggable after dropping it (scriptaculous)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, scriptaculous

probably best if i first just write my code down. i have:

```
<li class="sorted" id='<%= domid %>'>
    <%= horse.name %>
</li>
<%= draggable_element(domid, :ghosting=>true) %>
```

after the drop on some "box" the draggable element with name = horse.name stays on it. i want to delete it(the name). i was trying different things.

supposedly i will have to write plain javascript(i am not sure if thats the case but) if i do that i have problems with getting the parent element id that i have to insert in js.

```
var mydrag = new Draggable(domid, { ghosting: true });
// then destroy it when you don't need it anymore
mydrag.destroy();
```

how can i get proper domid. sth like this.parentNode.id? i also tried

```
 <%= draggable_element(domid, :ghosting=>true, :endeffect => "this.hide();") %>
```

without success.

so my question is how to remove the element after drag?

Answer (score 1):

You can use endeffect, like this:

```
var mydrag = new Draggable(domid, { ghosting: true, endeffect:function() { $(domid).hide() } });
```

Comment: i can only try your version like this: 
     <%= draggable_element(domid, :ghosting=>true, :endeffect => "function() { $(#{domid}).hide() }" ) %>

because i cant get the variable(!domid!) that represents parent dom element of draggable into javascript.
and if i try it like this(with draggable_element rails scriptaculous helper) it really seems to disappear but just for a second. and is then again at my mouse and also on the drop receiving element. i also tried .remove() and .destroy() instead of hide but it doesnt work. 

thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: actually it is just hidden behind an on hover effect of the droppable element i just noticed. so it is shown again when i go off of it.

Comment: I am not familiar with RoR, but you can decalre "domid" as a global variable, then you can access it inside your function.